# How to generate unique code in INSERT inside MERGE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, unique-constraint, sql-merge

In the Target table there is a PK column `usr_cd` which doesn't exist in the Source table. Hence, while inserting from Source to Target I want to generate a unique code. How can I achieve this when I am using `MERGE` statement?

Following options are tried without luck:

1. Sequence object: Can't use inside `MERGE`.
2. SP call: Can't execute SP inside `MERGE` in `INSERT`.
3. Function call: Won't help as I can't use sequence object inside UDF. Also if I store a unique value in a table, I won't be able to update inside UDF.
4. Adding code in Source table: Can't be used as some records will be updated and some will be inserted, hence it will break the sequence.

Adding default to Target table is one option but I want to avoid that.

Let me know if there is any other way of achieving this while using `MERGE`.

Comment: I don't get it. Why not simply use an identity column? That's the best solution to this kind of problems.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I can't use identity as I need to track these inserted records separately.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the docs for [`NEXT VALUE FOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx) say:

> **Limitations and Restrictions**
>
> The `NEXT VALUE FOR` function cannot be used in the following
>   situations:
>
> In a `MERGE` statement. (Except when the `NEXT VALUE FOR` function is
>   used in a default constraint in the target table and default is used
>   in the `CREATE` statement of the `MERGE` statement.)

So, if you don't want to use `NEXT VALUE FOR` as a default constraint in the Target table definition or simple `IDENTITY`, the only other thing that I can think of is a trigger. An [`INSTEAD OF INSERT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx) trigger.

Comment: Looks like there is no other option, its better to go for separate update and insert with joins (at least I can use sequence object) rather than merge in this scenario.

Comment: @RajeshBhat, yes, using separate `INSERT` and `UPDATE` is definitely an option.